# No puede desactivar Input mediante JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html5

Amigos una ayuda, no puedo desactivar `input`, probé de ambas formas:

```
$('input[name=txtApepaterno').val("prueba");
$( "#txtApepaterno" ).prop( "disabled", true );
document.getElementById("txtApepaterno").disabled = true;
```

Si me llena pero no desactiva, cabe resaltar que el `input` lo creo con Javascript html dinámico.

Comment: Pasa tu código html

Comment: pasa el código donde creas ese input

Comment: Tienes que confirmar que el id del input sea `txtApepaterno`. A mi me funciona perfectamente

Comment: $( "#txtApepaterno" ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );

Answer (score 0):

tengo algunas observaciones sobre tu script.

Aqui hay te falta cerrar con ']'

```
$('input[name=txtApepaterno').val("prueba");
```

Noto que primero quieres buscar por nombre del input y luego para desactivarlo buscas por id, esto solo funcionara a menos que el input tenga el mismo nombre y id, pero me parece que por ahi puede venir el error.

Me tome el tiempo de hacer un ejemplo funcional para el caso que comentas.

```js
function setValue() {
  $('input[name=txtApepaterno]').val("prueba");
}

function usingProp() {
  $("#txtApepaterno" ).prop( "disabled", true );
}

function usingGetElementById() {
  document.getElementById("txtApepaterno").disabled = true;
}

function activeInput(){
  $( "#txtApepaterno" ).prop( "disabled", false );
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  

  <input id="txtApepaterno" name="txtApepaterno" />

  <ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:setValue();"> Setear valor </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:usingProp();"> Desactivar usando Prop </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:usingGetElementById();"> Desactivar usando getElementById </a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:activeInput();"> Volver a activar </a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con jquery, ojala te sirva y puedas guiarte

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input id="txtApepaterno" type="text"/>
  <button id="disableit">Deshabilitar</button>
  <button id="enableit">Habilitar</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  $("#disableit").on('click',() => {
      $("#txtApepaterno").prop( "disabled", true );
  });

  $("#enableit").on('click',() => {
      $("#txtApepaterno").prop( "disabled", false );
  });

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 
  $("#disableit").on('click',() => {
      $("#txtApepaterno").prop( "disabled", true );
  });
  
  $("#enableit").on('click',() => {
      $("#txtApepaterno").prop( "disabled", false );
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input id="txtApepaterno" type="text"/>
  <button id="disableit">Deshabilitar</button>
  <button id="enableit">Habilitar</button>
```